# application crashed due to regex function . which stops intent to switch from one to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener, buttonclick

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText etEmail;
    private EditText etPassword;
    private TextView tvLogin;
    private TextView tvSignup;
    private Button btnSignin, btSignup;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    updateUI();
```

***Here the button signup is used to switch the activity from main to registration set bt on click listener but when i use to run the app and click on that button the app get crashed and displayed a meassage unfortunatly the app stopped***

```
    btSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent up = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registration.class);
            startActivity(up);
        }
    });
}

private void updateUI() {
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    tvLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLogin);
    btnSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSignup);


    String regexPassword = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[~`!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\)\\-_\\+=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\;:\"<>,./\\?]).{8,}";
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(MainActivity.this, R.id.etEmail, android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, R.string.etEmailerr);
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(MainActivity.this, R.id.etPassword, regexPassword, R.string.etPasserr);

    btnSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (awesomeValidation.validate()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Recieved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    });
}


public void btnLogin_Click(View v) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait....", "Processing...", true);

    (firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(etEmail.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString()))
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LOGIN SUCCESSFULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent signin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
                        startActivity(signin);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

***I don't get the point why this is happning help me out from this issue***

Comment: maybe it's good to share logcat too so that we may know what exception/error it is.

Comment: Share logcat pls.

Comment: you are using two click listenres for same button I guess! in the XML side for the sigIn button you have na ONCLICK tag there already and again you are having the java based click listener in the Activity java code

Comment: 03-12 16:32:58.958 9802-9802/com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement, PID: 9802'     @Umair

Comment: 03-12 16:32:58.958 9802-9802/com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement, PID: 9802  @CagriYalcin

Comment: nope just used only in activity java code @Rizwanatta

Comment: those are just the starting lines please edit the question and add full logcat there

Comment: 38:00.602 12000-12000/com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10065: Read-only file system :38:09.658 12000-12000/com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement, PID: 12000 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement/com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement.Registration}: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 33:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d]){6,} cont...

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:6980

Comment: Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 33:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d]){6,}at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381) at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.Validator.set(SourceFile:31)at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.Validator.set(SourceFile:46) **already took 3 comment box and yet not finished** @Rizwanatta

Comment: Fix your regex pattern.

Comment: like @CagriYalcin yes there should be a red bug prompting in your target activity saying that your RegExpression pattern is not ok! so please fix that

Comment: @CagriYalcin i have solved ,this is due to the regex function.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep the below code out side of your `onCreate()` method

```
btSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent up = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registration.class);
        startActivity(up);
    }
});
```

Comment: this did't helped!

Comment: OK in that case can you please share the XML file of your UI.

Comment: from where do i find it. xml of UI i did't get you

Comment: Just copy and paste your code of the XML file in which you have kept your button for SignUp and SignIn etc.

Comment: <Button
android:id="@+id/btSignup"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="43dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:text="new user ? click here"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogin"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.097" />

Comment: OK can you show me the error message you are getting while crash in the Logcat.

Comment: <Button
android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
android:layout_width="203dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
android:text="Login"
android:textSize="20sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.689" />

Comment: 38:00.602 12000-12000/com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10065: Read-only file system :38:09.658 12000-12000/com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement, PID: 12000 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement/com.example.sharanshu.projectmanagement.Registration}: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 33:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d]){6,} cont...

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:6980

Comment: Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 33:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d]){6,}at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381) at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.Validator.set(SourceFile:31)at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.Validator.set(SourceFile:46) already took 3 comment box and yet not finished